# Monogame sdl2 error on rider and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monogame, rider

I'am trying to use monogame with Rider and make a basic template for project :

https://github.com/bussiere/MonoGameRiderTemplate

So far so good now i have an sdl2 error :

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Sdl:GetVersion (Sdl/Version&)
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SdlGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) <0x412db940 + 0x000f7> in :0 
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.PlatformCreate (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) <0x412db290 + 0x00027> in :0 
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () <0x412d8250 + 0x008d3> in :0 
at Example.Game1..ctor () <0x412d7f50 + 0x0000f> in :0 
at Example.Program.Main () <0x412d7d50 + 0x00027> in :0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Sdl:GetVersion (Sdl/Version&)
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SdlGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) <0x412db940 + 0x000f7> in :0 
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.PlatformCreate (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) <0x412db290 + 0x00027> in :0 
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () <0x412d8250 + 0x008d3> in :0 
at Example.Game1..ctor () <0x412d7f50 + 0x0000f> in :0 
at Example.Program.Main () <0x412d7d50 + 0x00027> in :0
```

i think that i came from the sdl2 lib missing i've put them on 
https://github.com/bussiere/MonoGameRiderTemplate/tree/master/Example/lib

```
Example/lib/
```

And i think that the solution may be on the MonoGame.Framework.dll.config file :

https://github.com/bussiere/MonoGameRiderTemplate/blob/master/Example/MonoGame.Framework.dll.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="SDL2.dll" os="osx" target="./lib/darwin-x86_64/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib"/>
    <dllmap dll="soft_oal.dll" os="osx" target="./lib/darwin-x86_64/libopenal.1.dylib" />
    <dllmap dll="SDL2.dll" os="linux" cpu="x86" target="./lib/linux-i686/libSDL2-2.0.so.0"/>
    <dllmap dll="soft_oal.dll" os="linux" cpu="x86" target="./lib/linux-i686/libopenal.so.1" />
    <dllmap dll="SDL2.dll" os="linux" cpu="x86-64" target="./lib/linux-x86_64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0"/>
    <dllmap dll="soft_oal.dll" os="linux" cpu="x86-64" target="./lib/linux-x86_64/libopenal.so.1" />
</configuration>
```

So if anyone have any ideas ...

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
It turns out that SDL2 was not installed.

The 2 necessary packages are :

- libsdl2-2.0-0
- libsdl2-dev ( not sure it's mandatory )

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to update sdl to 2.0.5 or the latest version